# Javascript won't recognize variables I've set

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've looked at a few similar questions on here but I'm not quite sure they're quite related to what I'm dealing with (or perhaps they are and I'm just a dingus). I'm trying to create a sticky header using the scroll event but for some reason, it won't read my header variable. I've tried defining it both inside and outside the function to no success. I continue to get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property" These are the scripts I've tried:

```js
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;
window.addEventListener ("scroll", function () {testFunction()});
function testFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
<style>

.myheader {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="myheader" id="myHeader">
  <h2>My Header</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
  <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

And:

```js
window.addEventListener ("scroll", function testFunction()){
function testFunction() {
    var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
    var sticky = header.offsetTop;if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
}
```

```html
<head>
<style>

.myheader {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="myheader" id="myHeader">
  <h2>My Header</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
  <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Is there a conflict with how I'm defining the variable? The only thing my limited understanding of javascript can come up with is that I might be defining it as a local variable when I need to set it as a global one or vice versa.

### EDIT

Okay, so I've run this code snippet with the related HTML code and it works perfectly fine which confuses me even more. Hmm. So then it must be an error of some on-page element I'm using? I've placed the html in the custom html block on the page in WordPress so perhaps it's got something to do with that?

```js
window.addEventListener ("scroll", function () {testFunction()});
    var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
    var sticky = header.offsetTop;
function testFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
<style>

.myheader {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="myheader" id="myHeader">
  <h2>My Header</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
  <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried running the live demos you've included? They are all throwing errors. You need to provide a [mcve] (which means that you need some HTML in this case)

Comment: Unrelated but important: the language is always called JavaScript, or JS for short. Java is a completely different language. it's important since you may ask someone a question about English while referring to Dutch.

Comment: @Quentin You're correct, sorry about that. Now that I've added the same html that's on page, it works perfectly fine in the snippet, but I'm still getting property errors in the chrome console tools.

Comment: What errors? You didn't quote them in the question.

Comment: @Quentin Two uncaught type errors: Uncaught TypeError: "Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null"

Comment: Is that still the case when you use version 2 of your code with the `getElementById` calls inside the function? Have you checked that those elements with those IDs exist in the final HTML?

Comment: @Quentin You mean like this? "window.addEventListener ("scroll", function () {testFunction()});
function testFunction() {
    var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
    var sticky = header.offsetTop;" If so, no, I don't get of those errors but the header isn't sticky on scroll. All of the elements are on the page with their proper class.

Comment: If that gets rid of the error messages then it would be time to add logging to find out that `window.pageYOffset > sticky` and the two values that are used to calculate it actually are.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I feel like an idiot. The sticky header was working fine in this set of code:

```js
window.addEventListener ("scroll", function () {testFunction()});
function testFunction() {
    var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
    var sticky = header.offsetTop;
    if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
<style>

.myheader {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="myheader" id="myHeader">
  <h2>My Header</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
  <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

The issue was a conflict with my current website navbar overlapping this one. I didn't see that it was sticking as I scrolled.